# WordPress Could not insert post into database after importing website

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have imported a wordpress-based website from one server to another ... 
The website works fine but when i upload images using wp-admin it gives an error-

```
“info-box17.png” has failed to upload.
Could not insert post into the database
```

Comment: Can you please check the folder permissions of the upload folder and others, before get into the database.